# SaveChanges() will not update the actual table data in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For whatever reason, this code will only work while the program is running. It updates a row in db.Students, and prints it out to the list box. But once I exit, there is no table data in the database for that table. It simply won't save the changes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

        var st = new Student { StudentID = 1, StudentName = "Jack" };


        db.Students.Attach(st);
        db.Students.Add(st);
        db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (Student s in db.Students)
            listBox1.Items.Add(s.StudentName);
    }
```

EDIT - This is my context:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

----
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class Database1Entities1 : DbContext
    {
        public Database1Entities1()
            : base("name=Database1Entities1")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "For whatever reason, this code will only work while the program is running." -- you explain yourself later in the question, but I might suggest re-wording this sentence so people don't stop reading right there.  I mean, what  you describe is the case with all code.

Comment: It may seem a silly question, but have you checked the connection string in the app.config file? Perhaps it is pointing to a test database?

Comment: The connection string for the database looks "fine" to me. But that's coming from someone who has never set up a database before, on any format. I had thought it would be a simple thing using visual studio to simply have a local database created for read/write commands so I could work from there, but I've been stuck on writing to it for days now.

Comment: @user3503891 If you check that the `data source` value (the location of the database) and the `catalog` value (the name of the database) match the expected values, then you can be happy that it is pointing to the correct database.

Comment: are you regenerating the db every time you run the program?

Comment: or there any transactions or transaction scopes that exist int he program?

Comment: "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\e034514\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\Database1.mdf";Integrated Security=True"

Comment: I basically created an empty solution, added a service based database, made some tables, added the ado.net entity framework, and put in that code. It's extremely basic because I'm just trying to learn how to do something simple that works, so I can build on it.

Comment: @user3503891 did you add those tables from your code?

Comment: Not sure what you mean from my code. They are in the code as classes with member variables. I can access the "fields" with the dot notation.

Comment: I mean, I've constantly been trying everything I know, and every tutorial out there, with no success. If this is an issue, I can't imagine I'm the only one having it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();

        var st = new Student { StudentName = "Jack" };

        db.Students.Add(st);
        db.SaveChanges();

        foreach (Student s in db.Students)
            listBox1.Items.Add(s.StudentName);
    }
```

Remove:

`db.Students.Attach(st);`

For more information about what attach does read:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Comment: I added the attach when it wasn't working without it as that was a solution I googled after the initial problem. Without attach, it still does not write to the database.

Comment: fist off you don't set the id of a entry (EF will do that for you when it's saved) and attach won't add it to the database remove it and try again

Comment: I took out attach. It still does not write any data to the database. It stores it and recalls the data I put in for displaying it with the foreach loop. Then I exit the program, and nothing is in the database.

Comment: do you have at least 1 entry in the database?

Comment: No, it's an empty table as of yet.

Comment: @user3503891 can you show me your database context?

Comment: Okay, I put it up there.

Comment: try removing `OnModelCreating`